# apt-get failed to find any updates for Debian squeeze

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

```
# ls -F /etc/apt/
apt.conf.d/     preferences.old  sources.list     trustdb.gpg  trusted.gpg~
preferences.d/  secring.gpg      sources.list.d/  trusted.gpg  trusted.gpg.d/


# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.kr.debian.org/debian/ oldstable main
deb http://ftp.kr.debian.org/debian/ oldstable-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/ oldstable/updates main


# apt-get update
Hit http://ftp.kr.debian.org squeeze Release.gpg
Ign http://ftp.kr.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.kr.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release.gpg
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://ftp.kr.debian.org squeeze-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://ftp.kr.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.kr.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://ftp.kr.debian.org squeeze Release
Hit http://ftp.kr.debian.org squeeze-updates Release
Get:1 http://ftp.kr.debian.org squeeze/main amd64 Packages [6,527 kB]
Get:2 http://ftp.kr.debian.org squeeze-updates/main amd64 Packages [14 B]
Fetched 5,479 kB in 25s (213 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done


# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.


# dpkg -l libc6 | grep libc6
ii  libc6                                 2.11.3-4                     Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries


# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.10 (squeeze)
Release:        6.0.10
Codename:       squeeze


# w3m -dump ftp://ftp.kr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/e/eglibc/ | grep '2.11.3-4+deb6u4_amd64'
libc-bin_2.11.3-4+deb6u4_amd64.deb . . . . . . . . . Jan 28 01:26   732K
[ .. snipped ..]
```

Any insights?

Comment: It looks like cychoi is trying to update libc6 to a version that isn't vulnerable to the GHOST exploit.

Comment: Paste the output of `apt-cache policy libc6`, please. Also, please be explicit about what you expected. You expect libc6 to be upgraded, and it isn't being. Is that correct?

Comment: @FaheemMitha, Blake Frederick's answer solved the problem. I am waiting to be able to accept the answer. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: No problem - I happen to be working on the same exact thing at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might need to put this in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free

deb http://http.debian.net/debian squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
```

Source: https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using

Comment: Indeed; and as in this answer, I find it is almost always better to name *the specific release* that you want to be maintaining on your system.